# Fingerprint U Are U 4500 PowerBuilder

Tags: sdk, powerbuilder, fingerprint

I have an application C# for fingerprint reader u are u 4500 , so now I need to develop it in Powerbuilder. My question is if someone has any example of this app in powerbuilder.

Kind regards .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your fingerprint application I would recommend a COM visible dll (using C#) with exposed methods PowerBuilder can call to provide the functionality you require.  There are many examples of using COM with PowerBuilder online.  It is very unlikely someone will have 'any example of this app in powerbuilder' they are willing to share.

Comment: you're right. It's so hard to find any examples in Powerbuilder. My fingerprint reader(U.Are.U 4500) hardware is not supported for Powerbuilder.